Only one version works after deploying different versions of apps in docker container
I am trying to deploy different versions of apps to docker so that users can pickup the version they want to use. For example, I have two apps (programs-v1.0.0 and programs-v1.2.0) docker containers running on localhost, the one with port 8000 call be called without problem while the one with port 8080 cannot be called through the python script. There is no problem running both versions in interactive mode so I assume there is nothing wrong with the docker containers. I already changed the IP and port in python script for this service but don't know why programs-v1.2.0 cannot be called while program-v1.0.0 works fine. Any suggestions? Thanks.
(base) ➜ apps-dsu git:(main) ✗ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE       COMMAND         CREATED     STATUS           PORTS          NAMES
8bb4b104a541  programs-v1.2.0  "python3 server/main…"  35 minutes ago  Up 35 minutes        0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp  determined_kirch
df184b8387dd  programs-v1.0.0  "python3 server/main…"  41 minutes ago  Up 41 minutes        0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp  focused_diffie
6723d92116b2  b2eac8b8ed49   "/bin/sh"        2 months ago   Exited (130) 2 months ago              focused_galileo
278be857e7bb  b9810ceb74d9   "/bin/bash"       2 months ago   Exited (0) 2 months ago               lucid_carver
9a300254de3c  b9810ceb74d9   "/bin/bash"       2 months ago   Exited (129) 2 months ago              exciting_nightingale
27cf6d59ddc3  fb590c4e0825   "/bin/bash"       2 months ago   Exited (0) 2 months ago               busy_rubin
6a00ab114365  c2f43dad5e50   "/bin/bash"       2 months ago   Exited (0) 2 months ago               strange_mclaren
789eef79d1df  4eea455efdac   "/bin/bash"       2 months ago   Exited (127) 2 months ago              fervent_raman

(base) ➜  al-ex-gaines-thomas-programs-default python ../../../server/script-programs-v2-local-port-8080.py ex11-al -local_storage ./result-v1.2.0.zip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/danielsue/Soft/Anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/websockets/legacy/client.py", line 139, in read_http_response
    status_code, reason, headers = await read_response(self.reader)
  File "/Users/danielsue/Soft/Anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/websockets/legacy/http.py", line 120, in read_response
    status_line = await read_line(stream)
  File "/Users/danielsue/Soft/Anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/websockets/legacy/http.py", line 194, in read_line
    line = await stream.readline()
  File "/Users/danielsue/Soft/Anaconda3/lib/python3.8/asyncio/streams.py", line 540, in readline
    line = await self.readuntil(sep)
  File "/Users/danielsue/Soft/Anaconda3/lib/python3.8/asyncio/streams.py", line 632, in readuntil
    await self._wait_for_data('readuntil')
  File "/Users/danielsue/Soft/Anaconda3/lib/python3.8/asyncio/streams.py", line 517, in _wait_for_data
    await self._waiter
  File "/Users/danielsue/Soft/Anaconda3/lib/python3.8/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 848, in _read_ready__data_received
    data = self._sock.recv(self.max_size)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer

Thanks,
Daniel
Service of both programs-v1.2.0 and programs-v1.0.0 can be called.
Command I have used to build different versions of programs and run the container.
docker build -t programs --build-arg="v1.0.0" --tag=programs-v1.0.0 . -f docker/Dockerfile 
docker run -d -p 8000:8000 programs-v1.0.0


docker build -t programs --build-arg="v1.2.0" --tag=programs-v1.2.0 . -f docker/Dockerfile
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 programs-v1.2.0

Command I have used to call the service
python ../../../server/script-porgrams-v1.0.0-local-port-8000.py ex11-al  #(works fine)
python ../../../server/script-porgrams-v1.0.0-local-port-8080.py ex11-al  #(error)

Below is part of the script I have used
# Example of script-porgrams-v1.0.0-local-port-8000.py
...
if __name__ == "__main__":
    #Change the port accordingly when different versions are running, e.g., from 8000 to 8001.
    #BASE_URL = "34.132.141.185:8000/"
    BASE_URL = "127.0.0.1:8000/"
    RUN_URL = f"http://{BASE_URL}run/"

    # print('argument list', sys.argv)
    PREFIX = sys.argv[1]
    STORAGE_TYPE = sys.argv[2]
    OUTPUT_FILE_PATH = sys.argv[3]
    ARGS = sys.argv[4:]

    # Directory path can also be part of the argument, if local path is provided.
    DIRECTORY_PATH = "./"

    # Generate a random client_id
    client_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
    WS_URL = f"ws://{BASE_URL}ws/{client_id}"

    async def main():
        start_time = time.time()  # Start timing the process

        async with websockets.connect(WS_URL, ping_timeout=60) as websocket:
            print("WebSocket connection established.")

            # Create a task for receiving WebSocket messages
            ws_task = asyncio.create_task(receive_app_output(websocket))

            # Run the app process
            await run_app(
                RUN_URL,
                PREFIX,
                ARGS,
                DIRECTORY_PATH,
                OUTPUT_FILE_PATH,
                STORAGE_TYPE,
                client_id,
            )

            # Wait for the WebSocket task to complete
            await ws_task

        end_time = time.time()  # End timing the process
        print(f"Total process time: {end_time - start_time} seconds")

    asyncio.run(main())


# Example of script-porgrams-v1.0.0-local-port-8080.py
...
if __name__ == "__main__":
    #Change the port accordingly when different versions are running, e.g., from 8000 to 8001.
    #BASE_URL = "34.132.141.185:8000/"
    BASE_URL = "127.0.0.1:8080/"
    RUN_URL = f"http://{BASE_URL}run/"

    # print('argument list', sys.argv)
    PREFIX = sys.argv[1]
    STORAGE_TYPE = sys.argv[2]
    OUTPUT_FILE_PATH = sys.argv[3]
    ARGS = sys.argv[4:]

    # Directory path can also be part of the argument, if local path is provided.
    DIRECTORY_PATH = "./"

    # Generate a random client_id
    client_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
    WS_URL = f"ws://{BASE_URL}ws/{client_id}"

    async def main():
        start_time = time.time()  # Start timing the process

        async with websockets.connect(WS_URL, ping_timeout=60) as websocket:
            print("WebSocket connection established.")

            # Create a task for receiving WebSocket messages
            ws_task = asyncio.create_task(receive_app_output(websocket))

            # Run the app process
            await run_app(
                RUN_URL,
                PREFIX,
                ARGS,
                DIRECTORY_PATH,
                OUTPUT_FILE_PATH,
                STORAGE_TYPE,
                client_id,
            )

            # Wait for the WebSocket task to complete
            await ws_task

        end_time = time.time()  # End timing the process
        print(f"Total process time: {end_time - start_time} seconds")

    asyncio.run(main())

And the example of main.py is shown below. Please note I debug this on localhost, not google cloud.
@app.post("/run/")
async def run_app(
    prefix: str,
    args: str = "",
    input_zip: UploadFile = File(...),
    client_id: str = "",
    output_file_path: str = "./output_files.zip",
    storage_type: str = "-local_storage",
):
    timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
    parent_folder, output_zip_name = os.path.split(output_file_path)
    if storage_type == "-server_storage":
        print(f"Parent folder: {parent_folder}")
        folder_id = get_drive_folder_id(parent_folder)
        if folder_id is None:
            raise HTTPException(
                status_code=404, detail="Folder path does not exist in Google Drive"
            )
    output_zip_name = f"{os.path.splitext(output_zip_name)[0]}_{timestamp}.zip"
    input_zip_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), input_zip.filename)
    with open(input_zip_path, "wb+") as file_object:
        file_object.write(input_zip.file.read())
    with zipfile.ZipFile(input_zip_path, "r") as zip_ref:
        zip_ref.extractall(os.getcwd())

    # Find input files with the given prefix in the current directory
    input_files = [f for f in os.listdir(os.getcwd()) if f.startswith(prefix)]
    if not input_files:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=404, detail="No input files found with the given prefix"
        )

    if client_id not in active_websockets:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="WebSocket connection not found")

    websocket = active_websockets[client_id]

    app_path = "/usr/programs/src/project/makefile/programs-seq"
    # Construct the command
    cmd = [
        app_path,
        prefix,
    ] + args.split()

    process = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
        *cmd,
        stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
    )

    async for line in process.stdout:
        if line:
            await websocket.send_text(line.decode().strip())

    # Wait for the subprocess to finish
    await process.wait()

    # Capture the state of the directory after running app
    after_files = os.listdir(os.getcwd())

    # Determine which files were created by app
    new_files = [
        f
        for f in after_files
        if f.startswith((prefix + "_", "restart")) or f.startswith((prefix + "."))
    ]
    zip_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), output_zip_name)
    with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_path, "w") as zipf:
        for file_name in new_files:
            file_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), file_name)
            zipf.write(file_path, arcname=file_name)

    # Delete the files after a delay
    all_files_to_delete = (
        new_files
        + [zip_path, input_zip_path]
        # unzipped input files
        + [f for f in os.listdir(os.getcwd()) if f.startswith(prefix)]
    )
    asyncio.create_task(delete_files_later(all_files_to_delete))

    await websocket.send_text("END")

    if storage_type == "-local_storage":
        # Save locally
        return FileResponse(
            path=zip_path, media_type="application/zip", filename="output_files.zip"
        )

    elif storage_type == "-server_storage":
        # Upload to Google Drive and return the link
        gdrive_url = upload_to_google_drive(folder_id, zip_path)
        return {"url": gdrive_url}



Are the two scripts the same, except for the uvicorn.run(port=...) value?  Which specific line in which copy of the program is having the problem?  The BASE_URL values seem to be set to 127.0.0.1 and the listening port; are these programs trying to connect to themselves?

Yes, the main.py are the same. I just updated the description. uvicorn.run does not take effect so I have removed it.

These programs are standalone, just show some numerical results after reading input data.

did you tried to run only second with 8080? Maybe when both run at the same time then they have conflict with accessing the same external data and this makes problem.

maybe you should use logging to write information which lines of code are executed and what is in variables - to see what programs are doing,

@furas, I have tried to just run one version, port 8080 does not work on either version while port 8000 works fine. Thanks.

maybe you have some other program which uses port 8080. What if you use two ports different that 8080 - ie. 8000 and 9000 ?
